# Modeling a curved ring projected to a circular top

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, transforms

I'm trying to model a ring with a special form. On one axis, the sides wider towards the top and at the same time the top part is making an oval like in this drawing:

[image: ring drawing]

edit: here is an actual picture of the ring
[image: ring picture]

And Here is my failed attempt:

[image: my mesh]

How can you model a rign like this?

edit: I tryied to scale / move the upper part with proportional edit, but I cannot achieve a smooth result:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGy94dVU--A

Comment: Select all the flat faces at the top of the ring and with Proportional Editing turned on Scale on X

Comment: Select the top flat faces and use "to sphere" this should work and it's a very short way to do it, just make sure you're not using proportional editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a ring similar with your picture. The lenght is not the same, but the modeling way could work. First I did a structure with circules and arcs what are the edges and following the faces using Grid fill.

[image]

I am doing the process step by step to get the pictures:

- Draw the main edges using arcs and circles;
  [image]
- Do the surface with grid fill. I needed to cut the path of circles to use grid fill;
  [image]
- We have a simetric part, so we need only 1/4 of body and use mirror to get all ring;
  [image]

Create a cylinder to get the central hole through boolean operation;
[image]

- Use the modifier boolean difference between ring body and cylinder. Apply it;
  [image]

In edit mode, select the vertices from botton right of ring;
[image]

- Using the spin tool, do the botton half of the ring;
  [image]

[image]

- It was added the modifiers edge split and Subdivision surface;
- Do the top surface defining a vertice at center of circle and the edges to border;
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWuGj.jpg)

[image]

Comment: This shows a very nice result.. it would be a more useful answer if you illustrated enough of the process to give @denoise a shot at reproducing it?

Answer (score 3):

Your blueprint is not very clear but I've tried something, here it is, step by step, tell me if it's correct.

[image]

Comment: it looks very nice! but the sides should be flater. can you explain me al little bit more how did you did this?

Comment: fater? it fits your blueprint, except the top circle but you didn't give any top view, plus I think your blueprint wasn't completely explicit, so it's only a guess... well to do it you need to put the blueprint as background, mirror, follow the shape with some extrude, move, delete, join, merge, etc...   ;)

Comment: how did you shaped the top part as a circle? di you joined the circle with the rest of the mesh?

Comment: I first made a square, then created a circle, deleted the square and joined with the rest of the mesh, but there might be other ways. If the top is fatter than what I've done, just move some edges.